# Bootstrap alert not dismissing when clicking `x` in Rails application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

The notification does not disappear when clicking the `x`.

I don't think there are any missing required css classes, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Before clicking `x`:

[image]

After clicking `x`:

[image]

**application.html.erb**

```
<html>
  <body>
    ...
    <% if flash[:notice] %>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade out in">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
            <span>&times;</span>
          </button>
          <%= flash[:notice] %>
        </div>
    <% elsif flash[:error] %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade out in">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
          <% flash[:error].each do |msg| %>
              <li>
                <%= msg %>
              </li>
          <% end %>
        </div>
    <% elsif flash[:alert] %>
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade out in">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
          <%= flash[:alert] %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Gemfile.rb**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

**application.scss**

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
```

Is there anything else you can recommend that I try?

Comment: did you correctly load the javascript for bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution.**

Adding `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` to application.js.

I wasn't aware this was required in addition to `@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';` in `application.scss`